# Text recogniser could not be set up on your device error

Tags: 7.0-nougat, ocr

I have a smartphone with stock ROM Android 7.0 (Nougat). I use OCR apps very often for scanning text documents. Previously, OCR used to work well, but recently I noticed that whatever OCR app I use, it always shows ***Text recogniser could not be set up on your device*** error.

Why is this happening and how to fix this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have updated version of Google play services or it's not disabled and many OCR apps offer a file to download for the functioning of the app

Comment: I have the latest version of Google Play Services and it's not disabled, and I have a strong internet connection.